# Div scroll when less than min-width

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have 2 divs, a sidebar and the main pane.

```
.main {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 400px;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 200px;
    right: 0;
    overflow: auto;
}

.leftSidebar {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

I want the main div to have a horizontal scrollbar when the size is less than 400px, but currently content just gets cuts it off when it is less. What am I missing?

If this helps, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4bgy8x8w/) is a demo of this. Changing the width of the window should ideally add a scrollbar to the main div, but it only puts the scrollbar on the entire window.

Comment: Can you recreate this on [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Solution: http://jsfiddle.net/nnt7ctjr/

By giving the `.main` a `min-width` you forced it to stay at those dimensions and overflow outside of the viewport, thus a scroll bar appeared for the entire screen.

So the solution is to mimic this effect within the `.main`. I created another object `span.content` and gave it the `min-width:400px;`. Now the text will retain the `400px` dimension while the `.main` div continues shrinking.

Comment: @mcmonkeys1 I believe it still works, JSFiddle added a console beneath the rendered HTML that's obscuring the horizontal scroll bar. If you inspect element and delete the console DOM Element you will see the scroll bar is there when you scroll horizontally.

Comment: Worked for me. Had an inner wrapping div with a min-width set but a parent div only had 100%. Once browser was reduced in size, scroll bar showed up and parent wrapping div did not match the inner div width.